# Redis Sentinel manual failover command timesout

Tags: redis, docker, redis-sentinel

Redis Sentinel manual failover command timesout

I have one Redis master, one slave, and one Sentinel monitoring them.  Everything seems to be working properly including failover when the master is killed.  But when I issue the SENTINEL FAILVER command Sentinel gets stuck in the state +failover-state-wait-promotion for a few minutes.  It seems like the Slave is not getting the promotion command.  This doesn't make sense because there doesn't seem to be any trouble with network communication from the Sentinel host to either of the Redis hosts.  I'm running all 3 of the procs in Docker containers, but I'm not sure how that could cause the problem.  I can run redis-cli from the Sentinel host (i.e. from inside the Docker container) and can remotely execute the slaveof command.  I can also monitor both Redis instances and see SENTINEL pings and info requests.  I looked at logs for the master and slave and see nothing abnormal.  Looking at [THIS](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1796) post and there does not seem to be any reason why Sentinel would consider the Redis instances invalid.

I'm fairly experienced with Sentinel, but rather new to Docker.  Not sure how to proceed determining what the problem is.  Any ideas?

#### Sentinel Log

> [8] 01 Jul 01:36:57.317 # Sentinel runid is c337f6f0dfa1d41357338591cd0181c07cb026d0                                                       
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:13.135 # +monitor master redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380 quorum 1                                                      
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:13.135 # +set master redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380 down-after-milliseconds 3100                                      
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:13.199 * +slave slave 10.19.8.3:6381 10.19.8.3 6381 @ redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380                                  
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.288 # Executing user requested FAILOVER of 'redis-holt-overflow'                                                       
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.288 # +new-epoch 1                                                                                                     
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.288 # +try-failover master redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380                                                          
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.352 # +vote-for-leader c337f6f0dfa1d41357338591cd0181c07cb026d0 1                                                      
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.352 # +elected-leader master redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380                                                        
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.352 # +failover-state-select-slave master redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380                                           
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.404 # +selected-slave slave 10.19.8.3:6381 10.19.8.3 6381 @ redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380                         
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.404 * +failover-state-send-slaveof-noone slave 10.19.8.3:6381 10.19.8.3 6381 @ redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380      
> [8] 01 Jul 01:38:42.488 * +failover-state-wait-promotion slave 10.19.8.3:6381 10.19.8.3 6381 @ redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380          
> [8] 01 Jul 01:41:42.565 # -failover-abort-slave-timeout master redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380

#### Redis Master Log

> [17] 01 Jul 01:13:58.251 # Server started, Redis version 2.8.21                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> [17] 01 Jul 01:13:58.252 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.                                                                                                                        
> [17] 01 Jul 01:13:58.252 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.     
> [17] 01 Jul 01:13:58.252 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
> [17] 01 Jul 01:13:58.252 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> [17] 01 Jul 01:13:58.252 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6380                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> [17] 01 Jul 01:34:45.796 * Slave 10.196.88.30:6381 asks for synchronization                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [17] 01 Jul 01:34:45.796 * Full resync requested by slave 10.196.88.30:6381                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [17] 01 Jul 01:34:45.796 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> [17] 01 Jul 01:34:45.797 * Background saving started by pid 20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
> [20] 01 Jul 01:34:45.798 * DB saved on disk                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [20] 01 Jul 01:34:45.799 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [17] 01 Jul 01:34:45.808 * Background saving terminated with success                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [17] 01 Jul 01:34:45.808 * Synchronization with slave 10.196.88.30:6381 succeeded                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
> [17] 01 Jul 01:38:42.343 # Connection with slave 10.196.88.30:6381 lost.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> [17] 01 Jul 01:38:43.275 * Slave 10.196.88.30:6381 asks for synchronization                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [17] 01 Jul 01:38:43.275 * Full resync requested by slave 10.196.88.30:6381                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [17] 01 Jul 01:38:43.275 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> [17] 01 Jul 01:38:43.275 * Background saving started by pid 21                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
> [21] 01 Jul 01:38:43.277 * DB saved on disk                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [21] 01 Jul 01:38:43.277 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [17] 01 Jul 01:38:43.368 * Background saving terminated with success                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [17] 01 Jul 01:38:43.368 * Synchronization with slave 10.196.88.30:6381 succeeded

#### Redis Slave Log

> [14] 01 Jul 01:15:51.435 # Server started, Redis version 2.8.21                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
> [14] 01 Jul 01:15:51.435 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.                                                                                                                         
> [14] 01 Jul 01:15:51.435 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.      
> [14] 01 Jul 01:15:51.435 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [14] 01 Jul 01:15:51.435 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
> [14] 01 Jul 01:15:51.435 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6381                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.088 * SLAVE OF 10.196.88.29:6380 enabled (user request)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.947 * Connecting to MASTER 10.196.88.29:6380                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.947 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.948 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.948 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.948 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.948 * Full resync from master: b912b647401917d52742c0eac3ae2f795f59f48f:1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.960 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 18 bytes from master                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.960 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Flushing old data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.960 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> [14] 01 Jul 01:34:45.960 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Finished with success                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:42.495 # Connection with master lost.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:42.495 * Caching the disconnected master state.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:42.495 * Discarding previously cached master state.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:42.495 * MASTER MODE enabled (user request)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:42.495 # CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:42.506 * SLAVE OF 10.196.88.29:6380 enabled (user request)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.425 * Connecting to MASTER 10.196.88.29:6380                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.426 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.426 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.427 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.427 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.427 * Full resync from master: b912b647401917d52742c0eac3ae2f795f59f48f:10930                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.520 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 18 bytes from master                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.520 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Flushing old data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.520 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> [14] 01 Jul 01:38:43.520 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Finished with success

#### Sentinel Config

> port 26379                                                     
> pidfile "/var/run/redis-sentinel.pid"                          
> logfile ""                                                     
> daemonize no
>
> ## Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
>
> dir "/data"                                                    
> sentinel monitor redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.2 6380 1          
> sentinel down-after-milliseconds redis-holt-overflow 3100      
> sentinel config-epoch redis-holt-overflow 0                    
> sentinel leader-epoch redis-holt-overflow 1                    
> sentinel known-slave redis-holt-overflow 10.19.8.3 6381        
> sentinel current-epoch 1

#### Redis & Sentinel Info:

> redis_version:2.8.21
> redis_git_sha1:00000000                                 
> redis_git_dirty:0                                       
> redis_build_id:551c16ab9d912477                         
> redis_mode:standalone                                   
> os:Linux 3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64               
> arch_bits:64                                            
> multiplexing_api:epoll                                  
> gcc_version:4.7.2                                       
> process_id:13                                           
> run_id:7e1a1b6c844a969424d16f3efa116707ea7a60bf         
> tcp_port:6380                                           
> uptime_in_seconds:1312                                  
> uptime_in_days:0                                        
> hz:10                                                   
> lru_clock:9642428                                       
> config_file:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are running into the "docker network" issue. If you look in your logs they are showing different IPs. This is due to detection of what IP is connected from during discovery. Are these on different docker hosts?

From the documentation:

> Since Sentinels auto detect slaves using masters INFO output information, the detected slaves will not be reachable, and Sentinel will never be able to failover the master, since there are no good slaves from the point of view of the system, so there is currently no way to monitor with Sentinel a set of master and slave instances deployed with Docker, unless you instruct Docker to map the port 1:1.

For sentinel a docker image can be found at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/joshula/redis-sentinel/ which shows the use of announce-ip and bind to set it up.

For more details, see http://redis.io/topics/sentinel specifically the Docker section where it goes into detail on how to set things up in Docker to handle the situation.

Comment: Yup, good point.  But I'm mapping my ports 1-to-1.  Thanks, for the idea though!

Comment: Hmm, you're getting different IP addresses via discovery than you are in config. For example you config says the master is at 10.19.8.2  yet the Redis slave thinks it is at 10.196.88.29, and the master thinks the slave is at 10.196.88.30 instead of 10.19.8.3.  Seeing the "lost connection" entries does not jive with manual favor via sentinel failure command. Also note that something told the slave to slave to 10.196.88.29 not 10.19.8.2. If you are mapping 1:1 you would use the IP of the host machine, not the container.

Comment: Oh crud, sorry that was me messing with the IP addresses.  Just a bad copy/paste job.

Comment: *However* I did notice that I have a second Docker container running along side the Master and Slave instances.  These other Docker containers are monitoring the Redis instances and essentially acting as health checks to synchronize with Consul.  If I turn these second Docker containers off then Sentinel manual failover resumes functioning as expected.  So there appears to be some subtle interaction between Docker and Sentinel.  Still investigating and I will post what I find once I figure this out.  Thanks again, The Real.

Answer (score 0):

Dog gone it, yeah it was one of the scripts. It was essentially triggering in the interim period when both Redis instances are masters and preemptively reverting the promoted slave back to slave-status. It's been a long week.